# How to enable the user to copy the description of UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

After tapping a UIButton, I'm displaying the UIAlertView with multiple lines of message, how to enable that message to be copied/selected by user.

Comment: keep an option/button in alert view controller on its tap action copy the text programmatically  :)

Comment: You cannot, @souvickcse advice should help you get it done!

Comment: your question is good, but we can't handle the pasteboard concept in here

Comment: I have faces same issue sometime ago but i didn't find solution finally i decide to go with custom alert & achieve this thing.

Comment: Follow UIPasteboard, let user share data from one place to another.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add `UITextView` in `UIAlertView` ?

Try this :

```
UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World ! This is just a test."
                                                        message:@""
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
    textView.text = @"Hello World ! Hello World ! Hello World ! Hello World ! Hello World !";
    textView.editable = NO;
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [testAlert setValue: textView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [testAlert show];
```